# Extension of a linear map to a commutative graded algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, vector-spaces

Let's fix the notation,  $V=\bigoplus_{i\geq 0}{V^i}$ is a graded vector space and $\Lambda V$ is the free commutative graded algebra on $V$. I have been struggling to understand this example:

> Consider a graded vector space $V$ with basis $\{a, b\}$ such that $a \in V^2$ 
>   and $b \in V^5$. Now define a linear map $d$ (of degree $1$) by $da = 0$ and $db = a^3$.
>   It follows that $d$ extends uniquely to a derivation $d : \Lambda V → \Lambda V$.

The point of the example is to show that the derivation on $\Lambda V$ is completely determined by its values on $V$. So if i understand well, he considers a linear map $d:V\longrightarrow \Lambda V$ of degree one defined by $$d_2:V^2\longrightarrow \Lambda^3V; a\mapsto 0$$ (here  $\Lambda^kV$ is the set of elements of word length $k$) and

$$d_5:V^5\longrightarrow \Lambda^6V; b\mapsto a^3$$

The firt question that i'm stuck on is for $d_2(b)=a^3$, i mean $a^3$ is of length $3$, how it can be in $\Lambda^6V$. I really appreciate any help. Thanks !!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\Lambda^kV$ is not necessarily the set of elements of word length $k$. Rather than just word length, you need to consider the grading as well. Because $a$ lies in $\Lambda^2V$, $a^3$ lies in $\Lambda^6V.$

Comment: Isn't $\Lambda V$ graded by word length??? i mean $\Lambda V=\bigoplus_{i\geq 0}\Lambda^k V$ where $\Lambda^kV$ is the set of elements $a_1\otimes\cdots\otimes a_k$ of word length $k$?

Comment: No, that's only true if all the $a_i$ are in $V^1.$ Such a statement is true when dealing with ungraded vector spaces, but not with graded vector spaces.

Comment: Thank you David for your help. Then how is $\Lambda V$ graded in this particular case ?

Comment: It will be graded by 2*number of a's+5*number of b's. So $a\otimes b\otimes b$ will be graded by 12, for example.

Comment: Are you saying that $\Lambda V$ is graded by the degree of elements and not their length?? that is $\Lambda V=\bigoplus_{i} (\Lambda V)^i$ where $(\Lambda V)^i$ is the set of elements of degree $i$?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am saying. When all elements have degree 1, this is the same as their length, but it is not the same in general.

Comment: Dear David that is not what i read in the litterature.. all the books define the grading on $\Lambda V$ induced from the tensor algebra $T(V)=\bigoplus_{i\geq 0}T^kV$ where $T^kV$ is the set of elements of length $k$. Hence $\Lambda V=\bigoplus \Lambda^kV$ where $\Lambda^kV$ is the set of elements of word length $k$..

Comment: May be he is using the fact that $V=V^2\oplus V^5$ hence $\Lambda V=\Lambda V^2 \otimes \Lambda V^5$ and when he says $\Lambda^6V$ he means $\bigoplus_{i+j=6}\Lambda^iV^2\otimes \Lambda^jV^5$ and then by $a^3$ he actually means $a\otimes a\otimes a \otimes 1\otimes 1\otimes 1$ where $a\otimes a\otimes a\in \Lambda^3V^2$ and $1\otimes 1\otimes 1\in \Lambda^3 V^5$?

Comment: Are said books defining the grading where $V$ is an ungraded vector space or a graded vector space? As I said, that definition is correct for ungraded vector spaces, but is wrong for graded vector spaces.

Comment: it is always graded since we use the grading on $V$ to take the quotient of $T(V)$ by the ideal generated by $x\otimes y=(-1)^{|x||y|}y\otimes x$. What about the comment i added about $\Lambda V=\Lambda V^2\otimes V^5$ is that explanation for $a^3\in \Lambda^6V$ correct ?

Comment: That explanation is wrong; if your book is defining it that way, then your book is also wrong. If that were the definition, then the grading on the vector space $V$ would be completely unnecessary. Can you write down the exact definition in your book?

Comment: Actually sorry: The definition is CORRECT, but it coincides with my definition. The grading on the tensor algebra is what I am saying it is, and just because the tensor algebra is the sum of the $T^kV$ does not mean the $T^kV$ provide the grading for it.

Comment: Dear David thank you for your patience. I thought the grading on an algebra $A$ is a way of writing it $A=\bigoplus_{i\geq 0}A_i$, am i getting it wrong??? what is the grading then ?

Comment: That is true; however, here, there are two different possible gradings on the tensor algebra. There is the grading given by the direct sum. However, there is also the grading where you use that the direct sum of two graded vector spaces is a graded vector space. So for example, $T^0V\oplus V\oplus T^2V$ would be generated by $1,a,b,a^2,b^2,ab,ba,$ of degrees $0,2,5,4,10,7,7$ respectively. The grading on the tensor algebra comes from the individual gradings on the vector spaces, not from the direct sum.

Comment: ok i see, now the only problem in the example i gave is how $d(a)=0$, is $0$ of degree $3$??

Comment: $0$ does not have a designated degree; if you have a grading $\oplus_{i\ge 0}A_i$, then $0$ is in all the $A_i.$